# what is a good method to insert a <img src="..." /> into a <option> </option> in HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html

use javascript or other method ?
have any recommendation?

Comment: If you want a something that works in all browsers, you will have to code it out of an unordered list and style it to look like a select and add some good old JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMAGE tag can not be within OPTION one (as per HTML4.01 and XHTML1.0). Apply it as a background image (of an option element) instead.

```
...
<option style="background-image:url(...) ...">...</option>
...
```

Also note that some browsers don't allow much styling on select and option elements. For example, Safari doesn't support "background-color" on option elements (there's a [WebKit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=9846) filed back in '06 :))

I've heard that Chrome has similar "issues" as well.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend you to use CSS. For example:

```
<select style="width: 100px;">
<option style="background-image: url(/images/a.png);">First option</option>
<option style="background-image: url(/images/b.png);">Second option</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use fontAwesome instead, to show some 'img'. For example, using &#xF046 can show a checkbox image. It's better than nothing. Or you can edit the font to show a simple image.